# JS function mouseleave() exclude context menu

Tags: jquery

When the mouse is on the context menu, mouseleave event is triggered, how to avoid this?

The goal is that when the mouse is on the right click menu/context menu, the `$('.modal')` should not show

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $(document).mouseleave(function(e) { 
    if ((Cookies.get("visited_here") != 'exactly')) {
      // $('.modal').css('display','block');
    }   
  });    
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Also didn't understand that you but you're setting the eventhandler in a timeout... That can't be what you want.... Either use ready or delegate

Comment: you are not helping at all

Answer (score 0):

A moveLeave on document is a weird thing to have...  But if you really can't exclude the event handler form triggering on context menu. Then add another mouseleave event on a context menu or a parent to it and use it to catch the event before it reaches the document root.

```
$("#elementId").mouseleave(function(e){event.stopPropagation();});
```

But this comes with a few drawbacks you might want to read up on.